# how to directly interact with selenium webdriver from java console same as python console?

Tags: java, python, selenium, webdriver

How can I directly interact with selenium webdriver from java console like in python console?

For example in Python, I open Python console and have these operations:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  #after this command from python console browser is launched
driver.get("http://www.google.com") #any commands I type from python console, it will directly interact with browser
```

How do I do the same operations above in Java/webdriver console? Because I don't want to complete the codes in Java then run it?

Comment: java is a compiled language and python is an interpreted language. You can't enter java code line by line in the console because for the java code to be run, it must be in the jar format

Answer (score 1):

[Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) is a non-compiled Java language that, among other things, provides a [console](http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovyconsole.html) that allows you to do exactly what you are asking for. Groovy is 99.99% code [compatible with Java](http://www.groovy-lang.org/differences.html).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you simply want to create a webdriver object in Java and then access some website. If that is correct, its quite easy.

You would construct a Chrome WebDriver object called "driver" as such:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

And then you would call the "get" method of this object and pass it some URL:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```